# Regex checking string for a specific character

Tags: regex

**Requirements:**
1. first character is a number
2. string contains two letters
3. space anywhere in the string

I was able to code for (1) and (2) but unsure how to insert (3) in the existing code.

```
[0-9].*?[a-zA-Z].*?[a-zA-Z].*
```

**The following should pass without the quote**:
"12as "
"63 1/2 W Blanche St"
"12A Elray Road"
"2332 Jones Rd, Apt # 5"
"2  Jones Rd, Apt # 5"
"3 Jones Rd P.O Box"
"4 Jones Rd, abc"
"5 Jones - dfe"

Comment: a) is space an optional character ? if not than how `12as` should pass ? b) string contains two letters is it a minimum value of letters in string ?

Comment: space is not an optional character, there must be a space somewhere in the sting. "12as " has a space at the end. Correct a string should contain a minimum of two letters.

Comment: Your regex seems fine only caveat is no consideration for space to be must, [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/grTAns/1/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern is on the right track.  One simple fix here would be to add a positive lookahead `(?=.* )` which adds an assertion that a space character occurs in the string.

```
^[0-9](?=.* ).*?[a-zA-Z].*[a-zA-Z].*$
```

### Demo

This works by requiring that the string starts with a number (`[0-9]`), and contains two mandatory letters (`[a-zA-Z]`).  The lookahead `(?=.* )` asserts that the string contains at least one space.

Comment: `.?` wasn't there at first place, it was appearing as such due to wrong formatting

Comment: @CodeManiac Sorry, I can only comment on what I actually see.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the expression you desire to design would be that simple, we could start with this low boundary expression:

```
^[0-9]+(?:[A-Za-z]{1,2})?[A-Za-z0-9\s,.\/#-]+$
```

#### [DEMO 1](https://regex101.com/r/SNTtc2/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern is not taking the mandatory space into account. You could use a positive lookahead to assert that there is at least a single space by matching 0+ times a non whitespace char and then a space `(?=\S* )`

As you use `.*` to match any char, you might also make use of a negated character class `[^a-zA-Z\r\n]` to match not a-zA-Z or a newline and then do match a-zA-Z

```
^[0-9](?=\S* )[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z][^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z].*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7rWvPk/1)

You might also use a positive lookahead to assert 2 times a char a-zA-Z. Then match a single space and then the rest of the string.

```
^[0-9](?=(?:[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z]){2})\S* .*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]` Match a digit
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `(?:[^a-zA-Z\r\n]*[a-zA-Z]){2}` Repeating group, match 2 times a-zA-Z
- `)` Close positive lookahead
- `\S* .*` Match 0+ times a non whitespace char, then the mandatory space followed by matching any char except a newline
- `$` Assert end of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kWMNx2/1)